# Magento 2.2.5 page and block module not displaying grid and button

Tags: magento2, cms-block, cms-pages, magento-2.2.5

I just installed Magento 2.2.5 but in `admin > content > page` the page grid and the button are not displaying. Even in the block the same issue happens, records grid and button is not displaying. Remaining things are working well.

**I checked in console but no error is displaying.**

Please check the following screenshot for more details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you checked browser console logs and Magento logs?

Comment: Yes I checked the browser console as well as magento log but not getting any error.

Comment: try to flush cache and then again deploy admin content  hope it will help

Comment: I did but same issue. Still not dislpaying

Comment: Have you reindex data?

Comment: Yes many times. but still same issue

Comment: try after disabled external modules.

Comment: You've said "I just install Magento 2.2.5" but still there is clearly third party extension blurred out in admin menu .... please disable all the third party extensions, it is most probably the cause of the error.

Comment: Yes I disable all the extension but still that is not loading I think it is some js issue

Comment: you can see errors in browser console.

Comment: Pages & block ui component not loaded because of third party extension have bad/wrong ui component syntax.  not all M2.x extension support with M2.2.5. I've M2.x extension from some vendor, and I got the problem. 
so, I try to remove thats extension.. but i got the problem like this. https://prnt.sc/kl5j2r

Comment: May I know which external modules you installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Commands.

1. empty var folders,

   `rm -rf  generated/metadata
   rm -rf  generated/code
   rm -rf pub/static`  without .htaccess file
2. enable back developer mode,

   `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

mode    to  the production  mode    and vice    versa.  While   doing   this,   it  truncates   the var/di, var/generation, and var/view_preprocessed   directories.

3. upgrade modules,

   `php bin/magento     setup:upgrade`
4. compile,

   `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
5. deploy

   `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
6. cache remove and reindex,

   `php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

You said you have just installed Magento. So you have to run below set of commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Before running these commands first delete the content of following directories:

```
pub/static/frontend
var/view_preprocessed
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below command and check folder and file permission then check

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I did it already. but still not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to something like this.

1. Upload fresh magento 2.2.5 file to into current website. (Because if anything missing, then it overide)
2. Run following command from CLI.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```

Comment: Yes that things I have already done. I have replaced the module-cms but still the same issue.

Comment: I am talking about upload entire magento files, not only module-cms.